# Check for next empty row in column B and paste string into corresponding A Cell

Tags: vba, excel

The code that I currently have checks for the next empty cell in column B and pastes value into the empty B cell. I would like to check for the next empty row cell in column B and paste the string into the corresponding A cell.

This is what I have so far:

```
Dim Word As String
Word = "Apple"
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Word
```

I have researched previous answers and my VBA book, but I have not successfully found a solution.

Comment: The rest of the code is not related to the issue above. I am just trying to paste a given string into the A cell adjacent to the next empty B cell

Comment: Here is what I have. On the click of a button the following code runs:Private Sub TextBox1_Click()

    Dim Title As String
    Title = "C. TEST PROCEDURE"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B56").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Title
    
        

End Sub

Comment: I would like to have the string pasted into the corresponding A cell. I hope that clarifies.

Comment: On a related topic, your original code snippet together with the narrative description was more than enough to explain the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `....Offset(1, -1) = Word`.

The `Offset` method works like:

```
Offset(_rows_, _columns_)
```

So if you put `-1` in the columns argument, it will put the value in the column to the *left*.

Comment: This seems like a promising answer. Thank you for explaining the arguments of Offset

Answer (score 0):

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B60000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -1) = Word

Comment: Ah, I see I was beaten to the punch.